# Is it possible pad a string using String.Format the same way as numbers?

Tags: c#, string

I know that you can write something like

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0:0000}", 11);
```

and it will output

```
    0011
```

I'm curious if it possible to pad the string the same way without writing custom formatter? E.g.

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00000000}", "string");
    // output: 00string
```

Comment: You can simply concatenate them

Comment: @Bahrom, I cannot "simply" concatenate them, strings can be of various length and I need to pad them to some specific length with zeros or other numbers.

Comment: Well, with strings you will have to do some calculation to get the length

Comment: @Timofeus why don't you use one of the padding methods?

Comment: In general, [String.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) should have everything you need and want.  But for this particular case - where you want zero-padding for a "string" (vs. a "number") - Ownen Pauling's response is spot-on.   [String.Padxxx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) is your friend.  Please upvote and "accept" his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String.PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.8) (or PadLeft, depending on your requirements).

> Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by
>   padding them on the right with a specified Unicode character, for a
>   specified total length.